# How to add files to trigger m2e lifecycle mapping execution of frontend npm on modification of source or resource

Tags: eclipse, npm, ember-cli, m2eclipse, m2e

How can I get m2e lifecycle mappings to run my **build-frontend** execution for eclipse incremental builds?   I want to enable changes to my **hbs** file auto generating the appropriate **js** file on save.

When updating eclipse project from maven pom or after a clean m2e executes the npm executions (including **build-frontend**).

After modifying my application.hbs file or a random java file in the project nothing happens.  NPM only runs if I modify package.json.

Is there a way to change the modification scope?

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
    ...
    <execution>
        <id>build-frontend</id>
        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>npm</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <arguments>run build</arguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    ...        
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
      <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          <pluginExecutions>
            <pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[0.0.23,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
              <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
              <goal>bower</goal>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                      <goal>ember</goal>
                    </goals>
                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                <action>
                    <execute>
                        <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                        <runOnConfiguration>true</runOnConfiguration>
                    </execute>
                </action>
            </pluginExecution>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I suspect the answer is... "you modify package.json to trigger incremental build and like it!"  because when I look in frontend-maven-plugin's code I see a hard coded link to just package.json

However, 0.0.24-SNAPHOT offers an ember mojo.  When we configure using that mojo eclipse works as expected.

```
@Override
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    if (!skip) {
        File packageJson = new File(workingDirectory, "package.json");
        if (buildContext == null || buildContext.hasDelta(packageJson) || !buildContext
                .isIncremental()) {
            try {
                ProxyConfig proxyConfig = MojoUtils.getProxyConfig(session, decrypter);
                new FrontendPluginFactory(workingDirectory, proxyConfig).getNpmRunner()
                        .execute(arguments);
            }
            catch (TaskRunnerException e) {
                throw new MojoFailureException("Failed to run task", e);
            }
        } else {
            getLog().info("Skipping npm install as package.json unchanged");
        }
    }
}
```